# Programm doesn't work for numbers larger than 1000

Tags: c++

I have written this simple code to implement Eratosthenes algorithm to compute the prime numbers and type them in some ordered way. The problem is that it doesn't work for numbers larger than 1020. Can somebody tells me the reason of this?  When I run it, Eclipse can not launch the exe file and stops computing the numbers.
The same code written in Java works well for numbers under one billion, though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int* a = new int[N];

    int i , j, k, cnt = 0;
        for(a[1] = 0, i = 2; i <= N; i++) a[i] = 1;
    for(i = 2; i <= N/2; i++)
        for(j = 2; j <= N/i; j++)
            a[i*j] = 0;


        for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            if(a[i]) {
                cout<< i ;
                int lengthi = (int)floor(log10((float)i));
                int lengthN = (int)floor(log10((float)N)) + 1;
                    for(k = 0; k < lengthN - lengthi + 1; k++)
                         cout<<' ';
                cnt++;
                if(cnt%10==0) cout<<'\n';
            }

    delete [] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`. It's much better. You seem to be messing with `i` too much as well, which is another reason it's good to declare what you use within the for loop.

Comment: You have undefined behavior in your program. You read and write beyond the boundaries of the memory allocated for `a`. Remember that array indexing starts with zero, and the last index is the size minus one.

Comment: You might want to consider using brackets for your for loops...

Answer (score 3):

Your formatting is horrendous, but after converting it to use `std::vector` instead of manually managing the loop, it works fine:

http://ideone.com/y2CML7

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    int N = 1020;

    std::vector<int> a;
    a.resize(N);

    int i, j, k, cnt = 0;
    a[0] = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < N; i++) // fixed your indexing here
    {   
        a[i] = 1;
    }

    for(i = 2; i <= N/2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 2; j <= N/i; j++)
        {
            a[i*j] = 0; // I haven't done the math, but this may go out of bounds as well
        }
    }


    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]) 
        {
            std::cout << i;
            int lengthi = (int)std::floor(std::log10((float)i));
            int lengthN = (int)std::floor(std::log10((float)N)) + 1;
            for(k = 0; k < lengthN - lengthi + 1; k++)
            {
                std::cout << ' ';
            }
            cnt++;

            if(cnt%10==0)
            {
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or a simplified version of the algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>


struct moduloFunctor
{
    int mod;

    moduloFunctor(int m) : mod(m) {}

    bool operator()(int i)
    {
        return (i % mod == 0 && i != mod);
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int maximum = 1020;
    //std::cin >> maximum;
    numbers.reserve(maximum - 1); // starting at 2
    for (int i = 2; i <= maximum; ++i)
    {
        numbers.push_back(i);
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    do
    {
        moduloFunctor func(numbers[cnt++]);
        numbers.erase(std::remove_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), func), numbers.end()); 
    } while (cnt < numbers.size());

    std::cout << "Primes:  " << std::endl;
    std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want  a fixed number N, and the formatting is done by Eclipse. Thank you so much Zac for your comment, it is better to try to write in your fashion

Comment: You can put the `std::cin >> N;` back in there with no problem.  I used a constant to check it in ideone.  You can also simplify your implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: Use `resize` instead of `reserve`. And you still access `a[N]` which is outside of boundary.

Comment: Fixed the first boundary issue (noted the 2nd potential one).  However, the algorithm itself could be simplified a lot (simplified version shown).

Comment: The first version should probably do `a.resize(N + 1);` because the code still accesses `a[N]`

Comment: Thank you so much Zac, but your implementation does not use the Eratosthenes sieve.

Comment: Eratosthenes Sieve is the process by which you eliminate numbers that cannot possibly be prime by eliminating all multiples of lower prime numbers until your desired maximum.  That is exactly what the 2nd implementation does.  http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Arithmetic/Eratosthenes.shtml

Comment: One note:  you can actually stop the loop in the modified implementation once `numbers[cnt++] > sqrt(maximum)`.